# Despite installing a Java SDK, I'm getting the error "To use the keytool command you need to install a JDK"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm following [Facebook's SDK instructions to generate a hash key](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#samples).

It says to run the following command to generate the hash on OSX:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

So I paste that code into my Android Studio terminal (i've also tried regular terminal)

however this returns the following error:

[image]

I clicked More Info and then [installed Java for Mac OSX](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp).

However I'm still getting the error and prompt to install a JDK.

I restarted my computer and that didn't fix the problem.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you might have installed the JRE rather than the JDK, Try https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Is the JDK on your PATH? In other words, open Terminal and run ```which keytool```. If it can't find it, then you should run the installer to create all of the proper symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to setup [*JAVA_HOME* environment variable](https://www.alex-arriaga.com/how-to-set-java_home-in-mac-os-x-high-sierra/)